# Using child process id in arguments to child, especially log file

Tags: bash, process, jobs

We can access the process id of the current SHELL process with `$$`, like so:

```
$ echo $$
9777
```

But, this is the pid of the current process, the shell - not a child process.

And, we can reference the process id of the last, **backgrounded** child process, like so:

```
$ date &
[1] 10765
Thu Aug 14 10:30:04 CDT 2014
[1]+  Done                    date
$ echo $!
10765
```

(**Note**: I rearranged the above output to make it more readable.  The prompt may appear in the middle of the output text.)

I don't *think* there is a way to *directly* pass a child's process to itself.  So, what is the simplest way to embed a child's process id in its arguments, especially a log file?

This is my best approach, at the moment:

```
$ eval "date >& /tmp/log &"; wait; mv /tmp/log /tmp/log.$!
[1] 10884
[1]+  Done                    date &>/tmp/log
$ eval "date >& /tmp/log &"; wait; mv /tmp/log /tmp/log.$!
[1] 10891
[1]+  Done                    date &>/tmp/log
$ ls /tmp/log*
/tmp/log.10884  /tmp/log.10891
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same effect?  Is there another magic shell variable that is interpreted as the child process id during the evaluation of the child's input arguments?  I don't see how, without some serious internal shell magic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a child's PID as an argument to the child because the argument list is constructed before the child is created.

However, you can cheat. If the child process you want to create is a simple utility (as opposed to a bash pipeline or sequence of bash commands), you can use an explicit `bash` child process and pass its PID to the command, or use it as the name of a log file:

```
bash -c 'date >&/tmp/log.$$' &
```

This relies on the fact that when `bash` is invoked to execute a single command with `-c cmd`, it uses `exec` to replace itself with the command, with the consequence that the PID does not change. Hence, it is possible to use `$$` (which in this case will be interpreted by the child bash process, since it is single quoted) as the PID of the command process.

If the only point is to give a unique name to the log file, then it doesn't really matter whether the PID is that of the command or the child `bash` process, and then you could pass a more complex argument to `bash -c`.

Answer (score 2):

Summon a subshell and use `exec` so the child process would inherit the process id of the calling subshell:

```
( exec date &>"/tmp/log.$BASHPID" )
```

On shells not supporting `$BASHPID`, you can just summon a general shell:

```
/bin/bash -c 'exec date &>"/tmp/log.$$"'
```

Or

```
/bin/sh -c 'exec date >"/tmp/log.$$" 2>&1'
```

See [exec from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_%28computing%29).

Comment: Thanks for the additional examples!

Answer (score 0):

Version 4 of `bash` introduced a `BASHPID` variable which does store the process ID of the current shell, rather than the parent shell that `$$` stores.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That helps with subshells, like so: `$ echo $$ $BASHPID` => `9777 9777` versus `$ (echo $$ $BASHPID)` => `9777 11884`.  But, I'm not sure how to use it for children that are *not* subshells.

Comment: Ah, ok, I misunderstood what you were asking.